# C++ how to initialize and fill 2D vector of class

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to c++, trying to figure out how to use vector's syntax.
Say I want to initialize and fill a 2D vector based on input

```
Cell {
    int x, y;
public:
    Cell(){};
    ....
};

Grid {
    vector<vector<Cell>> theGrid;

public:
    void init(int n);
};
```

whats wrong with this

```
void Grid::init(int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j){
            Cell c;
            theGrid.[i].emplace_back(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `theGrid.[i].emplace_back(c);` should be `theGrid[i].emplace_back(c);`

Comment: `theGrid.resize(n, vector<Cell>(n));` is all that's needed.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `resize` is not suitable in case if the vector is not empty.

Comment: ```class``` definition in ```C++``` requires ```class``` or ```struct``` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems there: syntax errors, access out of bounds, using loops instead of the STL power.

```
void Grid::init(int n){
    theGrid = std::vector<vector<Cell>>(n, std::vector<Cell>(n, Cell()));
}
```

Comment: so what is a more "vector" way to access every Cell in this 2D structure

Comment: foreach variant of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

As for your code:

```
theGrid.[i].emplace_back(c);
```

Here you have a "`.[i].`", so that is **syntax error**... So, we have to write the syntax correctly which yields:

```
theGrid[i].emplace_back(c);
```

**Or:**

```
theGrid.at(i).emplace_back(c);
```

You don't even *need* to do that... Just use the vector's constructor:

```
theGrid = std::vector<std::vector<Cell>>(n, std::vector<Cell>(n));
```